# after restroring tablespace table or view not exists

Tags: backup, restore, recovery, rman, oracle-19c

I've Oracle CDB with PDB

In the PDB I created a tablespace
then I created a table over this tablespace

after that, I login into RMAN for the CDB database then I make a backup using

```
backup database ;
```

then I drop the table using

```
drop table table1 purge
```

then I login to the RMAN FOR PDB
and making the following command

```
alter tablespace mytablesapce offline ; 
restore tablespace mytablesapce  ; 
recover tablespace mytablesapce  ;
alter tablespace mytablesapce online ;
```

every thing until now is correct

but the problem is when I'm trying to select from table1
give me

```
the table or view does not exist
```

Also, I tried to restore all database but the same problem

could you help me, thank you

Comment: Did you check the restore/recovery log ? Possibly put the log to verify